# After updating Xcode to IOS 9, app show small screen

Tags: ios9, xcode7

just update my Xcode and after that.
 The screen size is seem not to fit. 
  it shows black space on bottom and top.
 can any one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this problem.

I fixed it by going to Project Properties --> General--> App Icons and Launch Images-->Change "Launch Screen File" to "Main".

problem solved.

Cheers,